# How to add more constraints to Laravel Unique Validator

Tags: validation, laravel-5

So a user needs to `update` products and user's products must have unique names and I don't want the user to receive the error message `Product with same name already exists`

How do I tweak the Laravel's `unique` validator to do this

```
  $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `products` WHERE `name` = '$value' AND user_id != '$user_id' AND id != '$id' ";
```

This will ensure that if user decides to leave product name unchanged, there will not be any error message for `product name with same already exists` as long as it belongs to the same user and the product id remains same

I have tried this in FormRequest rules()

```
 $id = $this->route('id');
 $user_id = $this->user()->id;

 return [
'name'=>"unique:product,name,user_id,$user_id,id,$id"
 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a custom validation, here is my solution:

1. in class App\Providers\AppServiceProvider,change the boot function like this

   ```
    public function boot()
    {
           Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator\Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
               return new \App\CustomValidation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
           });
    }
   ```
2. add CustomValidation.php to app folder,code like this

   ```
    use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
    class CustomValidation extends Validator
    {

       public function validateCustomUnique($attribute, $value, $parameters)
       {
             //$attribute is the filed name which you want validate
             //$value is the value of that filed
             //$parameters is an array which you can pass extra paramter form validation
       }
   }
   ```
3. in FormRequest

   ```
   return [
       'name'=>"custom_unique:$paramter1,$params2,$paramter4"//these paramters will pass to validateCustomUnique function
   ];
   ```
4. do you validation from validateCustomUnique function then return true or false

Comment: Nice idea will look into it. Thanks